# ReadBeanPHP parameter bindings for several values

Tags: php, redbean

Reading the documentation at http://www.redbeanphp.com/querying it gave some examples for using parameter bindings. But I have some questions using it:

**Question 1:**

Here is the original example

```
R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM page WHERE title = :title',
    [':title' => 'home']
);
```

But what if I want to replace more than one value for search in the SQL statement (for example adding year)? Is it correct to write:

```
R::getAll( 'SELECT * FROM page WHERE title = :title AND year > :year',
    [':title' => 'home', ':year' => 2012]
);
```

**Question 2:**

This example uses question mark ? for replacement

```
R::getRow( 'SELECT * FROM page WHERE title LIKE ? LIMIT 1',
    [ '%Jazz%' ]
);
```

If I want to add year, should it be written like this by adding a second question mark in the query?

```
R::getRow( 'SELECT * FROM page WHERE title LIKE ? AND year > ? LIMIT 1',
    [ '%Jazz%', 2012 ]
);
```

**Question 3:**

So far the documentation only gave examples for getAll() and getRow() functions. Will it also work for  R::exec()? For example:

```
R::exec( 'UPDATE page SET title="test" WHERE id = ? AND year > ?',
    [ 101, 2012 ]
);

R::exec( 'UPDATE page SET title="test" WHERE id = :id AND year > :year',
    [ ':id' => 101, ':year' => 2012 ]
);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your answers are correct.

If you looked up into rb.php file you can find Facade class and its functions:

```
public static function exec( $sql, $bindings = array() )

public static function getAll( $sql, $bindings = array() )
```

Second parameter is array for bindings.